# Logging issue for akka typed 2.6.3

Tags: akka, slf4j

Logs have stopped working for me for akka typed actor(2.6.3). It was working well for classic actors.

Message is as:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
>
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add following dependency:

libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"